# Can I redirect instead of rewrite in register_taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi currently I show custom taxonomy with:

```
     $package_category = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'package-category', '', ', ' , '' );
        if(!empty($package_category)){
            echo '<div class="package-info">';
            echo '<span class="head">Categories: </span>';
            echo $package_category;
            echo '</div>';
    }
```

and

```
        register_taxonomy(
        "package-category", array("package"), array(
            "hierarchical" => true,
            "label" => "Package Categories", 
            "singular_label" => "Package Categories", 
            "rewrite" => array(
'slug' => '/')));
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('package-category', 'package');
```

Currently this lists a bunch of tags with a link to category/package-category/ but the "rewrite" =>  is causing issues as its actually overwritting category/

Is there a way to redirect to category/ instead of rewrite

Comment: Redirect _what_ exactly …? Rather unclear what you are asking, resp. what your actual problem is.

Comment: @CBroe I've added more information, basically I am getting all the tags from a list of posts in the wordpress admin

and I dont want the link to go to category/package-category/, i want it to go to the category/ only

Comment: So this is back-end only? Are normal front-end users still supposed to be able to use these links then (if they should show up anywhere)? If you generate this list yourself, then it would probably be best to manipulate the links in there directly, instead of trying to do this via any setting that could have unintended consequences elsewhere. The code of get_the_term_list is rather minimal, so you should easily be able to replace that with your own function that manipulates the links to your liking. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/#source

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer:

```
'rewrite' => array( 
'slug'          => '.',
'with_front'    => false 
),
```

worked for me